# Apex Class get all field values, inlinehelptext, description and labels

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have my LWC calling the apex class in JS with `@wire(certObject)`

Currently, I can get the Label and the inlineHelpText no problem, but I have realized I also want to inclue the value of the field and the description in my nested map, so it should result in something like
`{"fieldLabel" : ["value" , "inlineHelpText" , "description"]}` or even better `{"fieldLabel" : [{value : "fieldValue"}, {helpText : "inlineHelpText"}, {description : "fieldDesc"}]}`

but needs to iterate across all fields of my custom object.

I'm returning a string and plan to parse in JS then query each field with a conditional to one main picklist value set on the record. < this idea I'm now thinking should just happen in apex. (I am unsure what to change my `public static String getObject()` to so that I can return a JSON with my above example).

Here is my Apex class

```
public with sharing class certObject {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static String getObject(){
    
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> helpTexts = new Map<String, Map<String,String>>();

        for(SObjectField field : SObjectType.Certification__c.fields.getMap().values()) {
            DescribeFieldResult des = field.getDescribe();
            Map<String, String> fieldInfo = new Map<String, String>();
            fieldInfo.put(FIELDVALUE,des.getInlineHelpText());
            helpTexts.put(des.getLabel(), fieldInfo);
        }

        System.debug(helpTexts);
        String textString = JSON.serialize(helpTexts);
        return textString;

    }
}
```

.JS snippet (there is more but it's commented out right now)

```
@wire(GET_OBJECT)
    parse({error, data}){
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
            this.fieldData = JSON.parse(data);
            this.error = undefined;
            return this.fieldData;  
        } else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.fieldData = undefined;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use LWC's getObjectInfo API?

Comment: @sfdcfox I can do this for the value but I cannot get the help text or description.

Comment: Well, why do you need the description?

Comment: Because I'm using it for logic purposes - certain fields need to be displayed in the LWC based on text in the description.

Comment: I'd recommend that you not do this. If you need to attach custom metadata, I'd recommend that you use [Custom Metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5).

Comment: I'm hesitant on this, as values can't be changed without pushing a new update. I think I should provide more context. I'm creating a custom object that will house, say 40 text fields. I want to display certain ones based on the type of business this object is related to (a picklist field on the object). The fields are not on the page layout, but the LWC is. It needs to be forward facing for clients to see but also visible to internal SF users. (experience builder) This list may need to be updated frequently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134853/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-user-11223344).

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper class will be a better option than working with JSON. Create an inner class like this:

```
public class FieldWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Object fieldLabel{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String helpText{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String description{get;set;}
}
```

Put this data into a map where the key should be the API name of the field label and return the map of type `Map<String, FieldWrapper>`. you will be able to access this data in the same way you referred to previously.

**Iterating all fields in JS**

```
for(let field in data){
    let fieldInfo = data[field];
    console.log(fieldInfo.value);
    console.log(fieldInfo.helpText);
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for sending this, the wrapper class helps me a lot. However, I am struggling to get the value of the field. Do you know how I can get that?

Comment: you need to use the [getrecord](https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/03/lwc-uiRecordApi-getRecord-example.html) and getFieldValue methods to get that.